# asp.net life cycle controller with multiple views

Tags: c#, asp.net, lifecycle

I want to have a init, init complete, and unload events for my MVC application. Each controller has multiple views. So for each controller, I want to have the events fire off for each view. Is this possible?

Comment: These are winforms' lifecycle events. Mvc is a different approach requiring new mindset. Part of your code can be placed in the constructor of the controller and run for all actions, part of the code should be in action methods, or in a webapi called via Ajax, etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you will have to create a js file to implement these event handlers that you load for all views of the controller.

You can use the same js to make async calls to the server side methods if you need.

Comment: Is there anything I can do with the master file so it calls the event functions when the view opens?

Comment: MVC does not have a master file. You can use the layout page to do the same thing.